# Switch to a different IObservable if the first is empty

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm writing a function that retrieves news about a subject and feeds this news back via an IObservable return value.

However, I have several news sources. I don't want to use `Merge` to combine together these sources into one. Instead, what I'd like to do is order them by priority --

1. When my function gets called, the first news source is queried (which produces an IObservable representing that source).
2. If that news source's IObservable completes without returning any results, the next news source is queried.
3. If that second source completes without returning results, the final news source is queried.
4. This whole behavior is wrapped up into an observable I can return to the user.

Is this sort of behavior something I can accomplish using built-in Rx extension methods, or do I need to implement a custom class to handle this? How would I approach doing either?

Comment: Any help rewording this question would be appreciated too -- I did the best I could but the problem isn't easily translated to words.

Comment: What happens if source A returns results then completes? Go on to source B?

Comment: Also, what's the signature for the "News queryer" call? Does it already return `IObservable`?

Comment: @JerKimball If A returns results, we don't care about B or C. The news query calls all return `IObservable`.

Comment: To clarify also, if A does not return results and B *does*, we don't care about C.

Comment: Querying an `IObservable` doesn't make much sense IMHO. Querying means "I ask a question and expect an immediate answer". An `IObservable` only accepts subscriptions. It calls back to its subscribers at a time of its own choosing. It is an active pusher, not something passive that you can pull at your preferred pace. When interacting with an `IObservable`, you are the observer, the passive side!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is undesirable in my opinion because it uses `Subject`, `Do`, and still subscribes to the second sequence when the first isn't empty. The latter can be a big problem if the second observable invokes anything nontrivial. I came up with the following solution instead:

```
public static IObservable<T> SwitchIfEmpty<T>(this IObservable<T> @this, IObservable<T> switchTo)
{
    if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@this));
    if (switchTo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(switchTo));
    return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
    {
        var source = @this.Replay(1);
        var switched = source.Any().SelectMany(any => any ? Observable.Empty<T>() : switchTo);
        return new CompositeDisposable(source.Concat(switched).Subscribe(obs), source.Connect());
    });
}
```

The name `SwitchIfEmpty` falls in line with the [existing RxJava implementation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#switchIfEmpty-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-). [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/489) is an ongoing discussion about incorporating some of the RxJava operators into RxNET.

I'm sure a custom `IObservable` implementation would be much more efficient than mine. You can find one [here](https://github.com/akarnokd/reactive-extensions/blob/2407d03b5b18b6cf83372cecd66ebf5f6d6f6558/reactive-extensions/observable/SwitchIfEmpty.cs) written by ReactiveX member [akarnokd](https://github.com/akarnokd). It's also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/akarnokd.reactive_extensions).

Answer (score 1):

### Edit from Original Poster:

I went with this answer, but turned this into an extension method --

```
/// <summary> Returns the elements of the first sequence, or the values in the second sequence if the first sequence is empty. </summary>
/// <param name="first"> The first sequence. </param>
/// <param name="second"> The second sequence. </param>
/// <typeparam name="T"> The type of elements in the sequence. </typeparam>
/// <returns> The <see cref="IObservable{T}"/> sequence. </returns>
public static IObservable<T> DefaultIfEmpty<T>(this IObservable<T> first, IObservable<T> second)
{
    var signal = new AsyncSubject<Unit>();
    var source1 = first.Do(item => { signal.OnNext(Unit.Default); signal.OnCompleted(); });
    var source2 = second.TakeUntil(signal);

    return source1.Concat(source2); // if source2 is cold, it won't invoke it until source1 is completed
}
```

### The original answer:

This might do the trick.

```
var signal1 = new AsyncSubject<Unit>();
var signal2 = new AsyncSubject<Unit>();
var source1 = a.Do(item => { signal1.onNext(Unit.Default); signal1.onCompleted(); });
var source2 = b.Do(item => { signal2.onNext(Unit.Default); signal2.onCompleted(); })).TakeUntil(signal1);
var source3 = c.TakeUntil(signal2.Merge(signal1));

return Observable.Concat(source1, source2, source3);
```

Edit: whoops, need a separate signal for the 2nd source and the 3rd doesnt need to signal anything.
Edit2: Whoops...types.  I'm used to RxJs :)

P.S. there's also less RX-y ways to do it that is probably a bit less typing:

```
var gotResult = false;
var source1 = a();
var source2 = Observable.Defer(() => return gotResult ? Observable.Empty<T>() : b());
var source3 = Observable.Defer(() => return gotResult ? Observable.Empty<T>() : c());
return Observable.Concat(source1, source2, source3).Do(_ => gotResult = true;);
```

Comment: Where would I actually put calls to get news in here?

Comment: If your calls return cold observables, then replace `a` `b` and `c` with the calls.  If they return hot observables (hopefully not!) then replace the variables with `Observable.Defer(() => callToNewSource())`

Comment: Sorry, totally missed those variables. I do have hot observables, since they're really `Task` that have been converted.

Comment: Yeah then `Observable.Defer(() => yourMethodThatReturnsTask().ToObservable())` is probably the best way to go.

Comment: For the first code snip, won't `TakeUntil` (a) cause the third observable to be subscribed, and (b) keep reading it until either A or B receives one item, which could take more time than C takes to return a result?

Comment: No, wait, because `c.TakeUntil` itself returns a cold observable (assuming `c` is cold).

Comment: I don't think you should have to use Do for this ... feels wrong ... it is for side-effects.

Comment: That doesn't work. The second is never evaluated even first one is empty.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It sounds like you can just use a plain-old `Amb` query.</strike>

EDIT: based on comment, `Amb` won't do it - give this a whack:

```
public static IObservable<T> SwitchIfEmpty<T>(
     this IObservable<T> first, 
     Func<IObservable<T>> second)
{
    return first.IsEmpty().FirstOrDefault() ? second() : first;
}
```

Test rig:

```
static Random r = new Random();
public IObservable<string> GetSource(string sourceName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Source {0} invoked", sourceName);
    return r.Next(0, 10) < 5 
        ? Observable.Empty<string>() 
        : Observable.Return("Article from " + sourceName);
}

void Main()
{
    var query = GetSource("A")
        .SwitchIfEmpty(() => GetSource("B"))
        .SwitchIfEmpty(() => GetSource("C"));

    using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }           
}
```

Some example runs:

```
Source A invoked
Article from A

Source A invoked
Source B invoked
Article from B

Source A invoked
Source B invoked
Source C invoked
Article from C
```

EDITEDIT:

You could also generalize it to this, I suppose:

```
public static IObservable<T> SwitchIf<T>(
    this IObservable<T> first, 
    Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<bool>> predicate, 
    Func<IObservable<T>> second)
{
    return predicate(first).FirstOrDefault() 
        ? second() 
        : first;
}
```

Comment: `Amb` will start observing all three at the same time, whereas I only want to start observing the second if the first completes with no results.

Comment: Ah, I see - you want the call to fetch skipped if it's not needed; ok, lemme chew on that a moment and I'll edit.

Comment: This is promising, but it requires a blocking call to FirstOrDefault() which in my scenario might be several seconds.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer True, there is that - actually, just had another idea...it's drastically different, so I'll spin a new answer

Comment: This requires subscribing to `first` and waiting for results from it twice.  Probably OK if you know it is an `AsyncSubject` or `Task`, but otherwise...probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach - fairly drastic in difference to other, so I'll spin a new answer:

Here it is with all sorts of fun debugging lines:

```
public static IObservable<T> FirstWithValues<T>(this IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> sources)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
    {
        // these are neat - if you set it's .Disposable field, and it already
        // had one in there, it'll auto-dispose it
        SerialDisposable disp = new SerialDisposable();
        // this will trigger our exit condition
        bool hadValues = false;
        // start on the first source (assumed to be in order of importance)
        var sourceWalker = sources.GetEnumerator();
        sourceWalker.MoveNext();

        IObserver<T> checker = null;
        checker = Observer.Create<T>(v => 
            {
                // Hey, we got a value - pass to the "real" observer and note we 
                // got values on the current source
                Console.WriteLine("Got value on source:" + v.ToString());
                hadValues = true;
                obs.OnNext(v);
            },
            ex => {
                // pass any errors immediately back to the real observer
                Console.WriteLine("Error on source, passing to observer");
                obs.OnError(ex);
            },
            () => {
                // A source completed; if it generated any values, we're done;                    
                if(hadValues)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Source completed, had values, so ending");
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                }
                // Otherwise, we need to check the next source in line...
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Source completed, no values, so moving to next source");
                    sourceWalker.MoveNext();
                    disp.Disposable = sourceWalker.Current.Subscribe(checker);
                }
            });
        // kick it off by subscribing our..."walker?" to the first source
        disp.Disposable = sourceWalker.Current.Subscribe(checker);
        return disp.Disposable;
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = new[]
{
    Observable.Defer(() => GetSource("A")), 
    Observable.Defer(() => GetSource("B")), 
    Observable.Defer(() => GetSource("C")), 
}.FirstWithValues();
```

Output:

```
Source A invoked
Got value on source:Article from A
Article from A
Source completed, had values, so ending

Source A invoked
Source completed, no values, so moving to next source
Source B invoked
Got value on source:Article from B
Article from B
Source completed, had values, so ending

Source A invoked
Source completed, no values, so moving to next source
Source B invoked
Source completed, no values, so moving to next source
Source C invoked
Got value on source:Article from C
Article from C
Source completed, had values, so ending
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-blocking version of JerKimball's [`SwitchIfEmpty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15210388/11178549) operator.

```
/// <summary>Returns the elements of the first sequence, or the elements of the
/// second sequence if the first sequence is empty.</summary>
public static IObservable<T> SwitchIfEmpty<T>(this IObservable<T> first,
    IObservable<T> second)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        bool isEmpty = true;
        return first
            .Do(_ => isEmpty = false)
            .Concat(Observable.If(() => isEmpty, second));
    });
}
```

And here is a version of the same operator that accepts multiple sequences, and returns the elements of the first non-empty sequence:

```
/// <summary>Returns the elements of the first non-empty sequence.</summary>
public static IObservable<T> SwitchIfEmpty<T>(params IObservable<T>[] sequences)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        bool isEmpty = true;
        return sequences
            .Select(s => s.Do(_ => isEmpty = false))
            .Select(s => Observable.If(() => isEmpty, s))
            .Concat();
    });
}
```

The `Observable.Defer` operator is used to prevent multiple subscriptions from sharing the same `bool isEmpty` state (more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843343/how-to-bind-a-non-disposable-object-with-each-subscription-of-a-cold-observable)).

Comment: Caution, the `Concat` operator [behaves wierdly](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634) in the current version of the Rx library (5.0.0). My advice is to use the equivalent `Merge(1)` operator instead, until the issue with the `Concat` is fixed. The `1` is the value of the `maxConcurrent` parameter. Setting this parameter to `1` means no concurrency.