# How to bind a non-disposable object with each subscription of a cold observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I am probably searching for a custom [`Observable.Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229585(v=vs.103)) method, that is not restricted to disposable resources. What I have is a cold `IObservable` that maintains some internal state, for example a `Random` instance. This instance should be bound not with the `IObservable` itself, but with each of its subscriptions. Each subscriber should use a different instance of this resource. Take a look for example to the `GetRandomNumbers` method below:

```
static IObservable<int> GetRandomNumbers()
{
    var random = new Random(0);
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Select(x => random.Next(1, 10))
        .Take(10);
}
```

This method generates 10 random numbers. The RNG is a `Random` instance initialized with a constant seed, so it should produce always the same 10 numbers. But alas it doesn't:

```
var stream = GetRandomNumbers();
Console.WriteLine($"Results A: {String.Join(", ", await stream.ToArray())}");
Console.WriteLine($"Results B: {String.Join(", ", await stream.ToArray())}");
```

Output:

```xml
Results A: 7, 8, 7, 6, 2, 6, 9, 4, 9, 3
Results B: 3, 5, 6, 5, 9, 1, 8, 9, 7, 3
```

Each subscriber of the `stream` observable gets a different set of numbers! What happens is that the same `Random` instance is used by all subscribers. This is not only undesirable, but it also creates the risk of corrupting the internal state of the object, since the `Random` class [is not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049467/is-c-sharp-random-number-generator-thread-safe).

My attempt to solve this problem was to use the `Using` operator, that has a `Func<TResource> resourceFactory` parameter:

```
static IObservable<int> GetRandomNumbers()
{
    return Observable.Using(() => new Random(0), random =>
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
            .Select(x => random.Next(1, 10))
            .Take(10)
    );
}
```

This would be a perfect solution if the `Random` was disposable (I tested it with a disposable class and worked as expected), but it's not, and so the code doesn't compile:

> The type 'System.Random' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResource' in the generic type or method 'Observable.Using<TResult, TResource>(Func, Func<TResource, IObservable>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Random' to 'System.IDisposable'.

Could you suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.Defer` is your friend if you want per-subscriber state.

Try this:

```
static IObservable<int> GetRandomNumbers() =>
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var random = new Random(0);
            return Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                .Select(x => random.Next(1, 10))
                .Take(10);
        });
```

My results:

```
Results A: 7, 8, 7, 6, 2, 6, 9, 4, 9, 3
Results B: 7, 8, 7, 6, 2, 6, 9, 4, 9, 3
```