# Skipping null values in a Scan method of an Observable collection

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I have an IObservable of items with a timestamp.
I use the Scan method to wrap each item and add a reference to the last valid wrapped item which was received.

```
IObservable<IWrappedItem> wrappedItems = 
  allItems.Scan(seedItem, 
    (lastWrappedItem, currentItem) => 
      WrapItem(currentItem, lastWrappedItem)));
```

This is the signature of `WrapItem`:

```
IWrappedItem WrapItem(Item currentItem, IWrappedItem lastItem);
```

We needed to change the `WrapItem` method so it skips invalid (not-null) items and returns null.
The seedItem will most probably be null, and the `WrapItem` method can handle it.

I need to update the way I use `Scan` with something like this:

```
IObservable<IWrappedItem> wrappedItems = allItems.Scan(seedItem, (lastWrappedItem, currentItem) => 
{
  IWrappedItem wrappedItem = WrapItem(currentItem, lastWrappedItem);
  if (wrappedItem == null)
  {
    // Do something clever to skip this invalid item
    // Next item should have a reference to lastWrappedItem
  }
  return wrappedItem;
}));
```

How can I implement this behavior without returning null values to the new collection, while keeping the Observable pattern?
Is there a different method that I should use instead of "Scan"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: @TheodorZoulias - Thanks for your important comment.
I tested it and saw that two parallel observers will not run concurrently, but the second one receives the last `lastWrappedItem` object of the first one as its seed instead of `null`. So I wrapped my observable with `Defer` as @Enigmativity suggested and it works correctly.

I found the answer to my question, I implemented a custom generic `Scan` method that receives the `WrapItem` function and ignores null values returned from it. It implements `Scan` using `Select` and `Where` methods.

This is my updated implementation:

```
public static IObservable<TAccumulate> ScanObservableAndFilterNulls<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IObservable<TSource> items, TAccumulate seed, Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> wrapItemFunc)
{
  // needed in order to protect from cases of concurrent observers
  // every observable will receive a new instance of the member `previousDataItem`
  return Observable.Defer(() =>
  {
    // use the seed before beginning the scan implementation
    TAccumulate lastWrappedItem = seed;
    // implement the custom Scan method
    return items.Select(item => wrapItemFunc(item, lastWrappedItem))
      .Where(wrappedItem =>
      {
        if (wrappedItem != null)
        {
          // update the lastWrappedItem only when the wrapped item is valid
          lastWrappedItem = wrappedItem;
          return true;
        }
        // skip invalid wrapped items, but keep the reference to the last valid item
        return false;
      });
  });
}
```

This method can be used like this:

```
public static IObservable<IWrappedItem> ScanAndWrapItems(IObservable<Item> allItems, IWrappedItem seedItem)
{
  return allItems.ScanObservableAndFilterNulls(seedItem, WrapItem);
}
```

I didn't benchmark the new method to assess the performance penalty, but I believe it would be slower than the original Scan method...

Comment: The `TAccumulate lastWrappedItem` could be shared by different subscribers. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843343/how-to-bind-a-non-disposable-object-with-each-subscription-of-a-cold-observable "How to bind a non-disposable object with each subscription of a cold observable?") question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias is right. Always wrap state in an `Observable.Defer(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to simply use the Where method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0

```cs
IObservable<IWrappedItem> wrappedItems = allItems.Where(item => item != null).Scan(seedItem, (lastWrappedItem, currentItem) => 
{
  IWrappedItem wrappedItem = WrapItem(currentItem, lastWrappedItem);
  if (wrappedItem == null)
  {
    // Do something clever to skip this invalid item
    // Next item should have a reference to lastWrappedItem
  }
  return wrappedItem;
}));
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, the received items are not null. The problem is that the result of the WrapItem method could be null.